# Larger payload in Ajax Call returning a 302 Status Code

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, http-status-code-302, jsonresult

I want my Edit All button to make an ajax call to send 300 items to my jsonresult controller method for updating, but it doesn't hit my endpoint at all and the network tab shows a Status Code of 302. It seems to hit my controller method and work just fine when I try sending in one or 10 items so I'm guessing it's related to the 300 being too much to pass in? I'm attaching part of my html + javascript function + ajax call + controller method.

I've looked at other answers but they seem to be related to log in authentication or scenarios where a 302 is expected. There were also posts that suggested sending in smaller arrays at a time but I wanted to be sure the issue was related first.

```js
$scope.saveAllDays = function () {
                    var newValue = angular.element("#editAll").val(); 
                    var savedCustomers = [];
                    angular.forEach(angular.element(".customer"), function (customer, index) {
                        var currentCustomerId = angular.element(customer).attr("id"); 
                        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.customers.length; i++) { 
                            if ($scope.customers[i].Id == currentCustomerId) {
                                var savedCustomer = $scope.customers[i]; 
                                savedCustomer.ArchiveDays = newValue;
                                savedCustomers.push(savedCustomer);
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                    })
                    console.log(savedCustomers);
                    $.ajax({  
                        type: "PUT",
                        url: "/JobArchive/UpdateArchivePeriods",
                        data: JSON.stringify(savedCustomers),
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: onUpdateAllSuccess, 
                        error: onUpdateAllError
                    })

                }
```

```html
<div id="archiveConfigTab" class="tab-pane fade">
                <div class="bumper"></div>
                <div class="container cust-body">
                    <div class="search">
                        <label>Search:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="nameInput" size="100" ng-model="customerName" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="customer-title">
                        Customers
                    </div>

                    <div id="editAllDays">
                        <p class="edit-all-btn pull-right">
                            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" ng-click="showEditAll($event)">Edit All <i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
                        </p>
                        <div class="edit-mode hidden">
                            <input type="number" id="editAll" placeholder="# of days" min="0" />
                            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" ng-click="saveAllDays()">Save</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="{{customer.Id}}" class="customer" ng-repeat="customer in customers | orderBy : 'Name' | filter : customerName">
                        <p class="cust-row">{{customer.Name}}</p>
                        <p class="cust-row pull-right">
                            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" ng-click="toggleInput($event)">edit <i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
                        </p>
                        <p>Archive Period: {{customer.ArchiveDays}} days</p>
                        <div class="edit-mode-row hidden">
                            <input type="number" ng-keypress="checkEnter($event, saveDays)" class="archivePeriod" placeholder="# of days" min="0" />
                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="saveDays($event)">save</button>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="bumper"></div>
            </div>
```

```
[HttpPut]
    public JsonResult UpdateArchivePeriods(List<LAG.Models.Customer> updatedCustomers)

    {
        List<ConfiguredCustomerViewModel> results = new List<ConfiguredCustomerViewModel>(); // Initialize List of stuff to return to front
        foreach (var customer in updatedCustomers) // Loop through and update each
        {
            bool updateSuccess = LAG.API.DAL.CustomerRepository.GetRepository().SaveArchiveDays(customer.ArchiveDays, customer.Id);
            if (updateSuccess)
            {
                ConfiguredCustomerViewModel result = new ConfiguredCustomerViewModel();
                result.Id = customer.Id;
                result.ArchiveDays = customer.ArchiveDays;
                results.Add(result);
            }
        }
        return Json(results);

    }
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your JsonResult method and see if it is even being hit. I bet it is not, and that you need to look elsewhere, such as your web server configuration, to find the source of this error.

Comment: Question - that's c# code at the bottom there, correct? You probably want to use that tag as that code is closer to whatever system is emitting the 302.

Comment: @TimGrant I did have a breakpoint in my JsonResult method which is how I knew my ajax call worked for smaller array sizes but not for the full 300 I wanted. I'm going to try trimming down the objects I'm trying to pass in to see if that works. Just added c# tag, thank you!

Comment: Ok then that's the proof. Something else on the API web server is preventing your code from running when the request payload is large. Maybe but not necessarily because the large request is corrupt.

Comment: @TimGrant I trimmed down each object to only include the two properties I really needed and it went through to the database successfully. I am a little worried about it not working with larger objects though cause I know I might need to do that in the future. Do you happen to know if the web server redirects with larger payloads in general?

Comment: I don't. I'm actually not much of a c# or iis expert. My advice is to look for info in your iis logs.

Comment: Thanks @TimGrant !

Comment: @wendyg Did you try changing `type: "PUT"` to type: `"POST"` and in your Controller: `[HttpPost]`?

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez Hey Danny, yeah I tried that yesterday and it still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Trimming down my object to only include the 2 properties I needed worked for me.

I'm still confused as to why I received a 302 trying to redirect me to an error page in the first place though since the amount of data I was passing in wasn't anywhere near the 5TB needed to trigger a 413 Status Code. It's really bugging me.